# Rails + AJAX: Load modal with ActiveRecord Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a `Product` model I would like my user to be able to click a link in the view which will cause a modal to show with data specific to a given `product`.  I have the product `id` stored in the links `data-attribute`.

```
# Modal
<div class="modal" id="product-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center"><strong>Nutrition Facts:</strong></h4>
      </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I have the links that users will click:

```
# They click the label containing the data-attribute
<% @products.each do |prod| %>
  <%= f.label prod.name, data: {id: prod.id}, class: "product-info" %>
<% end %>
```

This calls an ajax function:

```
$(".product-info").click(function() {
    url = "/products/" + $(this).data("id")
    $.get(url, function(data) {
       console.log(data) # nothing shows here
    }, 'script')
})
```

...finally I have my `products/show.js` view with the following:

```
$(".modal-body").html(<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => '/food_orders/nutrition', :locals => {prod: @product}) %>)
$("#product-modal").fadeIn();
console.log("Is this working?"); # I never see this in the console
```

and in my developer tools, the response to the ajax request contains `show.js` but it's never displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The whole issue was due to the fact that my erb was not in quotes.

I changed:

```
$(".modal-body").html(<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => '/food_orders/nutrition', :locals => {prod: @product}) %>)
```

to:

```
$(".modal-body").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => '/food_orders/nutrition', :locals => {prod: @product}) %>")
```